# UIPickerView in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am making an application of iphone, in which i have a table view, on every row of table view i have created a button programmatically & on its click method am showing picker view. Picker view showing perfectly, on picker view's toolbar i have 2 barbuttonitem named Done & Cancel. i have added below code in Picker view's delegate method

but button title is not changing with this delegate method

```
static int _selectedRow;

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        NSString *title = [pickarray objectAtIndex:_selectedRow];
        //[pickarray removeObjectAtIndex:_selectedRow];
        [pickarray insertObject:title atIndex:_selectedRow];
        [table reloadData];
}
```

Any ideas how to show selected row title on button?

Comment: Could you post some more context? It's not exactly clear what the problem is and what you're trying to do.

Why is the second statement in the method's body commented out?

Comment: I am not sure if I know what you are asking.
Also, please format your "code" so it shows up better.  Either use the code button in the editor or put 4 spaces in front of each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you assign the value of _selectedRow, or where you use the parameter "row" in didSelectRow.  I don't think your engine is connected to your wheels.

Comment: i have added below code 
-(IBAction)btnpickclick:(id)sender 
{ 
UIButton btn = (UIButton*)sender;
_selectedRow = btn.tag; 
tool.hidden = FALSE; 
pick.hidden = FALSE; 
} 
i am bit confused in didselectrow delegate of pickerview what should i write to get the title on button on selection pieckerview row.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the selected row data and assign it to your button text. Below is what I did in my code. See if this helps

```
[breedButton setTitle:[pickerData objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Do this in your picker delegate method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

breedButton is my button.
pickerData is my array of strings I am showing in the picker.
pickerView is my picker view object.

Comment: actually i have solved my issue regarding button's title. your solution is for for 1 button title but i have created 1 button in cellforrowatindexpath in tableview delegate, now the issue is i have to show button title is "select" cancel of pickerview. Any ideas?